# HDMI Audio not working on fresh Dell install

Tags: sound, hdmi, tv, output

Just installed Ubuntu on a Dell Studio 1535 laptop.  Everything is working except the audio on the HDMI connection (video via hdmi does work).  Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5850 @ 2.16GHz = thats the processor, and I can't find anything that indicates there is a seperate graphics card. When I boot to windows vista, it says "intel graphics", so I think it's all part of the board? In ubuntu it says the graphics driver is unknown. When I go in to the sound controls in Ubuntu, it only lists headphones and internal speakers as audio outputs, with not mention of HDMI.  Thoughts on how to correct?

Answer (score 1):

PulseAudio volume control fixed the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Comment: How? By going to the **Configuration** tab and choosing another **Profile** that includes **HDMI Output**?